# Can I use Twig in a FreeForm html field?

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform

Is it possible to use the {{ siteUrl }} Variable in a html Field in freeform? I tried it and it threw an error that the variable was not valid. Is it possible to use twig in a html field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kelsey: "Sorry, unfortunately you cannot, as these fields are pre-rendered beforehand. Kelsey Martens"